# EnableWebFluxSecurity contadiction with web dependency

Tags: spring-security, spring-webflux

I am trying to annotate  `SecurityWebFilterChain` class with `@EnableWebFluxSecurity` :

```
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class AccessIqWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
```

I am  getting the following error while boot the app:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.reactive.WebFluxSecurityConfiguration':
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field
>   'securityWebFilterChains'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class
>   path resource
>   [com/config/AccessIqWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain]:
>   Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested
>   exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   clientRegistrationRepository cannot be null

When I remove `compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")`. It works. but I need `compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")` for swagger, Mockmvc etc. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

[As stated in the reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-webflux), adding the `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency to your application will tell Spring Boot to configure it as a Spring MVC application.

You could give another hint to Spring Boot to make it still a Spring WebFlux application (through `SpringApplication.setWebApplicationType(WebApplicationType.REACTIVE)`), but it wouldn't help in your case:

- You have to use a swagger integration that's compatible with WebFlux (I don't know if that exists)
- You should consider [`WebTestClient`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#webtestclient) instead of MockMvc